# Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined error after upgrading React Native

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

Metro bundler building fails when running react-native app with the following error,

> bundling failed:
> node_modules/react-native-draftjs-render/index.js:app/node_modules/react-native-draftjs-render/index.js:
> Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

How to fix this..? I'm in the middle of upgrading my react-native project to 0.61.5. (I'm really new to react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come across this issue again while upgrading my project to React Native 0.63.2. I don't remember how I resolved this last time. This time I was using `react-native-draftjs-render` version `2.9.0` and the issue resolved after downgrading to `2.8.3`.